# Counting votes for candidates in a category and region

Tags: java, performance, object-oriented, functional-programming, collections

With the following code, I want to count the Vote objects from a collection, filtering on one of their fields, Candidate.

I have the feeling that I can get this done much more efficiently.

```
// Get all votes from the database
Collection<Vote> votes = getVotesFromCategoryAndRegion(c, r);

// Filter distinct candidates
Collection<Candidate> candidates = votes
            .stream()
            .map(Vote::getCandidate)
            .distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());


List<VoteResult> results = new ArrayList<>();


// If vote.candidate == candidate, candidates's vote counter ++
for (Candidate currentCandidate : candidates) {
      int currentVoteCount = 0;
      for (Vote v : votes)
          if (v.getCandidate().equals(currentCandidate))
              currentVoteCount++;

      results.add(new VoteResult(currentCandidate, currentVoteCount));
    }


    Collections.sort(results);
    return results;
```

If you have any suggestions, please tell.

Answer (score 2):

> can get this done much more efficiently.

Yes, I agree.

If C candidates each receive an average of V votes (total of C * V votes cast), then your complexity is quadratic in number of candidates: O(C * C * V).

There's nothing so bad about making a pair of linear passes, to accumulate candidates and then votes.

But there's no need, you can make a single pass to do both. Create a HashMap, iterate over all votes, probe the map to see if you should add a zero entry for a new candidate, and then increment the entry so you'll have vote totals at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You were right that this can be made in just one pass.  You are not aware of [Collectors.groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-).

It is basically a one-liner:

```
    Map<Candidate, Long> results1 = votes.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    Vote::getCandidate,
                    TreeMap::new,
                    Collectors.counting()));

    // Results are sorted, but by the key of the TreeMap: the Candidate name.
    results1.entrySet().stream().forEach(e ->
            System.out.printf("%30s: %d%n", e.getKey(), e.getValue()));

    List<VoteResult> results = results1.entrySet().stream()
            .map(e -> new VoteResult(e.getKey(), Math.toIntExact(e.getValue())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    // Results are sorted by VoteResult, which uses the vote count.
    Collections.sort(results);
    results.forEach(vr -> System.out.printf("%30s: %d%n", vr.getCandidate(), vr.getVoteCount()));
```

Note that `Candidate` must implement `Comparable` and that it must also define `equals()` and `hashCode`.  `VoteResult` must also implement `Comparable`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping over every candidate and every vote you could just loop over the votes and have a `Map<Candidate, Integer>` with vote count for every candidate. This way your code would have a complexity of \$O(n)\$ instead of \$O(n^2)\$ (at least I think so, I'm not sure about this but it should greatly improve performance nonetheless). Another advantage of this approach is that you wouldn't need to `distinct` all of these candidates which improves performance even more.

Here's more less how it could be improved (untested)

```
Collection<Vote> votes = getVotes(x, y);
Map<Candidate, Integer> votesPerCandidate = new HashMap<>();

for (Vote vote : votes) {
    int votes = votesPerCandidate.getOrDefault(vote.getCandidate(), 0);
    votesPerCandidate.put(vote.getCandidate(), votes + 1);
}

List<VoteResult> results = new ArrayList<>();
for (Map.Entry<Candidate, Integer> result : votesPerCandidate.entrySet()) {
    results.add(new VoteResult(result.getKey(), result.getValue());
}

Collections.sort(results);
return results;
```

Comment: In Java 8, the body of the first loop can be simplified to `votesPerCandidate.merge(vote.getCandidate(), 1, (v, one) -> v + one);`

Comment: @BenC What does the `(v, one) -> v + one` part exactly do?